# Tests with Sinon + Chai fail after refactor to implement promises

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, sinon, sinon-chai

I got a lot of callbacks in this application that ended up as a good example of a 'callback-hell'. Methods with 200 or 300 lines and 10, 15 nested callbacks each.

Then, as a good practice, I detached most of these callbacks, named then and created more organized 'then-chains' with Bluebird promises.

I don't know exactly why, since all tests and methods I have implemented are very similar to each other, two tests cases of the same method failed.

It was using Sinon to check whether or not the `next` function and a DAO method (that makes a Mongo query) were being called.

I then realized that what changed in this method was that I transfered some logic that was running in the beginning of that method to inside a promise.

The call to 'next' was not getting evaluated to `true` because the test didn't wait for the promise to complete and returned wrongly.

This is the part of the **test** that showed a bad behavior:

```
var nextSpy = sinon.spy();
var methodSpy = sinon.spy(my_controller.options.dao, "findAsync");

my_controller.sendMail(req, res, nextSpy);

expect(methodSpy.called).to.be.true;
expect(sendMailSpy.called).to.be.false;
```

I have changed the controller method, but basically, i had the logic inside of a promise. puting it out solves the problem.

Comment: your test is all sync, how should it know when the promise is finished?

Comment: Please show production code as well.